# Clean R data frame so that in a column no row value is bigger than 2 times next row value

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a data frame exemplified by the following

```
dist <- c(1.1,1.0,10.0,5.0,2.1,12.2,3.3,3.4)
id <- rep("A",length(dist))
df<-cbind.data.frame(id,dist)

df

  id dist
1  A  1.1
2  A  1.0
3  A 10.0
4  A  5.0
5  A  2.1
6  A 12.2
7  A  3.3
8  A  3.4
```

I need to clean it up so no row values in the dist column is bigger
than 2 times the next row value at any time. A cleaned up data frame would look
like this:

```
  id dist
1  A  1.1
2  A  1.0
5  A  2.1
7  A  3.3
8  A  3.4
```

I have tried making a function with a for loop and if statement to clean it

```
cleaner <-  function (df,dist,times_larger) {

              for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) {

                  if (df$dist[i] > df$dist[i+1]*times_larger){
                    df<-df[-i,]
                    break       
                  }
              }
              df
            }
```

Obviously if I dont break the loop it will create an error because 
the number of rows in df will change in the process. If I manually run the loop
on df several times:

```
df<-cleaner(df,"dist",2)
```

it will clean up as I want.

I have also tried different function constructions and applying it to the data frame with apply, but without any luck.

Do any have a good suggestion of either how to repeat the function on the data frame until it does not change anymore, a better function structure or maybe a better way of cleaning?

Any suggestions are most appreciated

Comment: Can you try fix() function?  You can just do it manually if the data frame isn't so big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `lead` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) #dplyr_0.4.0
filter(df, dist < 2 * lead(dist, default = Inf)) 
#    id dist
#1  A  1.1
#2  A  1.0
#3  A  2.1
#4  A  3.3
#5  A  3.4
```

Or using the similar method in `data.table`.  A new function `shift` is introduced in the devel version of data.table. We can specify the type to `lead`.  By default, it is `lag` and `fill` is NA.  Modify the `fill` to 'Inf' (inspired from @Marat Talipov's post).

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
setDT(df)[dist <2 *shift(dist,type='lead', fill=Inf)]
#   id dist
#1:  A  1.1
#2:  A  1.0
#3:  A  2.1
#4:  A  3.3
#5:  A  3.4
```

#### Update

If the value of 'dist' is equal to '2' times the next value, the above solutions removes that row.  In such cases,

```
setDT(df)[dist <2 *(shift(dist,type='lead',
             fill=Inf)+.Machine$double.eps)]
#    id dist
#1:  A  1.1
#2:  A  1.0
#3:  A  2.1
#4:  A  3.3
#5:  A  3.4
```

Using a different example as commented by @Henrik.

```
df1 <- data.frame(dist= as.numeric(3:1))
setDT(df1)[dist <2 *(shift(dist,type='lead', 
            fill=Inf)+.Machine$double.eps)]
#    dist
#1:    3
#2:    2
#3:    1
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(49)
df <- data.frame(id='A', dist=rnorm(1e7,20))
df1 <- copy(df)
akrun1 <- function() {filter(df, dist < 2 * lead(dist,
                                 default = Inf)) }
akrun2 <- function() {setDT(df1)[dist <2 *shift(dist,type='lead',
                                     fill=Inf)]}
marat <- function() {subset(df,dist < c(2*dist[-1],Inf))}
Colonel <- function() {df[with(df, dist<2*c(dist[-1], tail(dist,1))),]}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun1(), akrun2(), marat(), Colonel(), 
                                unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
# akrun1() 2.029087 1.990739 1.864697 1.965247 1.773722 1.727474    20  b  
# akrun2() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20  a   
# marat() 8.032147 8.137982 7.359821 7.937062 7.134686 5.837623     20  d
#Colonel() 7.094465 7.045000 6.473552 6.903460 6.197737 5.359575    20  c
```

Comment: @Henrik You are right.  Thanks.  All the current solutions does return only the 2 values.

Comment: `filter(df, dist < 2 * lead(dist, default = Inf))` works for me

Comment: @hadley Thanks a lot, I used the dplyr version, since my data frame had several sub groups it seemed natural. Only thing is that I have to filter several times; when values > 2*lead are filtered out, the resulting data frame may introduce new occurrences of leading values smaller than 2* the lagging value . This was not the case in my example though, so my bad. Thanks again for your quick and excellent replies.

Answer (score 6):

You can shift your `dist` column one element left, multiply it by two, and compare with the original `dist`:

```
subset(df,dist < c(2*dist[-1],Inf))
#  id dist
#1  A  1.1
#2  A  1.0
#5  A  2.1
#7  A  3.3
#8  A  3.4
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution:

```
> df[with(df, dist<2*c(dist[-1], tail(dist,1))),]
  id dist
1  A  1.1
2  A  1.0
5  A  2.1
7  A  3.3
8  A  3.4
```

If there are no zero elements:

```
df[with(df, dist/c(dist[-1], tail(dist,1)))<2,]
```

Comment: but what if some `dist` elements are zeroes?

Comment: exactly, your multiplication solution is better for general case!